# "Forward" components from Ant Design to be able to use them in component library loses type definitions

Tags: typescript, antd

Currently we want to use Ant Design in our applications as a UI framework. Also we have custom components composed from Ant Design components, as well as fully custom written components.

To let the team quickly see what components we have available, I want to showcase them in a component library.

To be able to show the Ant Design components, I have to forward them as as such:

e.g. for the Button component:

```
// button.ts
import Button from 'antd/es/button'
import 'antd/es/button/style'

export default Button
```

This works for displaying them in the component library. But importing from this component will lose the components' type definitions. This means that if one of the developers in our team uses this component instead of the button from Ant Design directly, they have type definition errors in their application.

In the end I would like the team to import all of their components from the component library (to act as a single source of truth), so I'm currently searching for a way to include the type definitions in this 'forwarded' component.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought I have not tried out, but would it work if you exported a new instance of `Button`? 
`export default new Button`

Comment: @Mathieu Thanks for the suggestion unfortunately that gives me the following error in my editor:

```(alias) new Button(props: Partial<{
    href: string;
    target?: string;
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
} & BaseButtonProps & Pick<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, "download" | ... 258 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & {
    ...;
} & Pick<...>>): Button
import Button
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
button.d.ts(67, 17): An argument for 'props' was not provided.
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I got too when trying it. Probably not the way to go, after seeing what would be necessary to make it work ^^" Sorry to not be more helpful!

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your suggestions anyways.